# Is there a tool to find html elements affected by certain css file

Tags: html, css

I've been working with [a jquery file uplouad plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) which has it's own CSS files, but when the plugin implemented in a web page that also has its own CSS file applied, the elements will have styles applied from multiple files, so what I need is a tool that enable me to select a CSS file and an HTML file than the tool should show all the elements affected by this file, I used Firebug but it only provide the opposite of what I need like selecting element and see all the CSS files affect the element, I think there must be a faster way to do it.

Comment: Opera-Dragonfly; Mozilla - Firebug(I think); Any IDE for web development(like Dreamweaver). There's a resources tab in Dragonfly(and maybe Firebug).

Comment: chrome also has a built in dom inspector

Comment: can you detail how to use the inspector to achieve what I need

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. 1"

Answer (score 1):

Fire bug https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/
or google developer tool 
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I think use notepad++ and do some pity, tool will help you but also you will become slave. Apply some of your mind, its easy for Press CTRL + F and search the hierarchy..

Also the browser with Developer Tool will help, but not sure ,who will teach you there :)